# How do I see unanswered questions with a certain tag?

Tags: support

When I sesarch for dd on the /tags page, it indicates there are 26 questions. However, when I click on the ["dd" tag](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dd) , I only see two questions.

I assume it's just showing me the unanswered questions, but how do I see the answered ones with the dd tag as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have the "unanswered" tab selected. Choose another tab, e.g. "newest", and it will show you all 26 [dd](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dd) questions:

[Screenshot of the dd tag page, unanswered tab http://so.mrozekma.com/unix-dd-unanswered.png](http://so.mrozekma.com/unix-dd-unanswered.png)
[Screenshot of the dd tag page, newest tab http://so.mrozekma.com/unix-dd-newest.png](http://so.mrozekma.com/unix-dd-newest.png)

The site remembers the last tab you had selected, so once you choose "newest" it will stay selected in the future